# Is it possible to solve the following problem without any coordinate system and if so, how?

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let $ABC$ be a triangle ($A \notin (BC)$) in the plane space. Let $x,y$ and $z$ be three reals and let $M, P$ and $S$ be the points defined by:
$$\vec{AM}=x\vec{AB},\quad \vec{AP}=y\vec{AC},\quad \vec{BS}=z\vec{BC}$$

1) Express $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ if the points $M$, $P$ and $S$ are collinear.
2) Express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ such that $S$ is the midpoint of $[MP]$.

I used the system $(A,\vec{AB},\vec{AC})$ in order to solve this exercise.

My question: Is it possible to solve this problem without any coordinate system and if so, how?

Comment: You could just draw lines parallel to $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$ through the relevant points, and then do the same thing you did with a coordinate system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Illustration]

[Menelaus' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) will provide the answer to 1) by simply talking about oriented length ratios along each edge, with no need for a coordinate system in the plane once you have accepted that theorem.

$$-1=\frac{AM}{MB}\cdot\frac{BS}{SC}\cdot\frac{CP}{PA}=
\frac{x}{1-x}\cdot\frac{z}{1-z}\cdot\frac{y-1}{-y}$$

With a slight modification, the same can be used for 2) as well. In this case, I'd consider $\triangle PSC$ as the triangle and $ABM$ as the collinear triple. Then the same theorem gives you

$$-1=\frac{PM}{MS}\cdot\frac{SB}{BC}\cdot\frac{CA}{AP}=
\frac{2}{-1}\cdot\frac{-z}{1}\cdot\frac{-1}{y}$$

Combine this with the first equation, and you can find both $y$ and $x$ from $z$.